# Firebase not uploading to firestore using .doc

Tags: javascript, html, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use firebase and stripe to set up payments on my website based on the source code found here: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe
I've tried resetting my rules for firestore and realtime database, but I keep getting stuck on .snapshot. I've looked in the debugger, and currentUser.uid is not null, but it is not creating a new entry in the database. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! First time using firebase so I am a little lost. At the moment, my rules files are the same as those linked in the github repo.

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((firebaseUser) => {
  if (firebaseUser) {
    currentUser = firebaseUser;
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection('stripe_customers')
      .doc(currentUser.uid)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        if (snapshot.data()) {
          customerData = snapshot.data();
          startDataListeners();
          document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block';
        } else {
          console.warn(
            `No Stripe customer found in Firestore for user: ${currentUser.uid}`
          );
        }
      });
  } else {
    document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'none';
    firebaseUI.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', firebaseUiConfig);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely nothing in the code you show even *tries* to create a document - .doc() just creates a reference to an *existing* document.

.onSnapshot establishes a *listener* for a first read and subsequent *changes* to an existing document; I'm not going to spend time searching the GitHub (even as I actually know the specific repository) for "startDataListeners()"

If you were expecting this code fragment to create a document, I suggest you spend a fair bit more time understanding what exactly this code is doing.  I strongly suspect the code sample you are using expects that the User documents *already exists* (i.e. that your *application* created them), and is simply trying to connect your *existing* user to a Stripe transaction

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet does not actually *create* any document, it simply tries to read an existing document.

Now, what you can do, is check if the document actually exists, which I assume

```
if (snapshot.data())
```

portion checks (*there should be a snapshot.exists property or method*).

However, if it doesn't exist, you will then have to create the document in the firestore database,

```
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection('stripe_customers')
  .doc(currentUser.uid)
  .create(YOUR_DATA_OBJECT)
```

This will create a document using the uid you provided in the request.
**If a document already exists, i.e., your check didn't work, it will throw an error, as firestore documents cannot be created twice.**